# extern variable and extern function issue between cpp files

Tags: c++

** This is a large project and this is just an abstraction **

I am NOT able to build when incorporating the global variable and global function in fileC.cpp.
But it works with fileB.cpp just fine.

I have tried a number of combinations so that I can use the function and variable through the 3 files???

```
//fileA.cpp

#include <fileC.cpp>

extern int dog;
extern void myFunc(int junk)
{
    //some stuff
}
```

---

```
//fileB.cpp

//Unsure of the connections but fileA works fine with fileB    
int dog;
void myFunc(int); //no issues here
```

---

```
//fileC.cpp

int dog;
void myFunc(int);//causes issues with building
```

Comment: `#include <fileB.cpp>`? WAT? Technically you can do that, but it's really not advised. create the proper `fileA.h` header file for `fileA.cpp`, and include that into fileB.cpp and fileC.cpp. Always try to keep your includes tidy, otherwise you bring havoc.

Comment: typo... it included fileC... and this is a large project that I am adding to.  The includes were set prior.  I am just trying to figure out how to use a global variable and function across multiple files.

Comment: Now it's `#include <fileC.cpp>`. Same thing. Only include header files.

Comment: Not same thing... it won't build!

Comment: Same thing in the meaning that it's a big no-no. You have to have these files: fileA.cpp with the proper fileA.h, and fileB.cpp and fileC.cpp both of them including fileA.h. Until you get this right you will just mess around.

Comment: This is a project that I have just joined.  I am responsible for monitoring some data in the program.  The hierarchy was built and not only that, there is no header file for fileA, but there is for fileB and fileC.  It's a mess.

Comment: cpp files - implementations, they only include h files. header files - interfaces. (sometimes they refer "definitions" for cpp files and "declarations" for h files).

Comment: Is it open source? Share a link.

Comment: It is legacy code and internal only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Csaba Toth in the comments.  This is a mess, and you should clean it properly.  Convince the people who put you on the project that it's worth taking the time to rewrite it with proper headers and source files.  It'll save them tons of development and support, and help to expose bugs before the customer finds it.

That said, you still need to deal with the extern.

Your choice 1 is very poor.  .cpp should never include another .cpp.  It's just short of a miracle that you don't get tons of "already defined" errors.

Choice 2 is defining another static-ish int in file B.  This will be a separate int from that in file C, and they can have different values.

What you need to do is declare file C's int as an `extern`.  You can do it in either the header or the cpp.  The trick is to make sure it's only instantiated in one place.

So, in some part of B, do this:

```
extern int dog;
```

This tells the compiler that there will be an int called `dog` by the time the program is ready to run.  The linker will then look for one-and-only-one instance of that variable - currently residing in fileC.cpp - and point everything to the same place.

Your choice 3 was giving you issues because you have two globally scoped variables of the same name.  Using the `extern` will solve this.

Generally, good coding structure would be:

#### Header files

- Make sure to have wrappers, either `#ifdef MYFILE_H` or `#pragma once` if it's supported, to make sure that a .h can never be included more than one time.
- Only put function declarations - you should have very few implementations, unless you're desperate to make it inline (and good compilers nowadays can optimize fine on their own for most situations). You should make sure any functions you implement are internal to that file only, and don't depend on other files.
- You can refer to other file global variables using `extern`.

#### Cpp files

The cleanest thing is to match implementations from your header, though compilers and linkers would let you implement anything anywhere.  The main rule to follow is that each function and each extern be implemented once and only once in all of your code.  There should only be one place with function `myFunc` and there should only be one place that declares `int dog` instead of `extern int dog`.  Both function declarations and `extern` variables tell the compiler "don't worry about this, I'll make sure it's done", and then the linker looks for it among all of your objects.

I'm guessing, from the fact that you didn't mention any errors in your choice 1 and choice 2, that you got as far as compiling, but never ran the linker.  My next guess is that this is a unix system, since Visual Studio takes care of both steps at once.  In that case, there must be some `make` system that will take care of building, or something.  You should've had errors with all three of your choices.

Comment: Yes it is Linux.  fileA to fileB works, but can't get fileC to work.  Have tried using fileB to contain the "extern"... no luck.  Again this is legacy code and those #includes are something I won't be able to alter.  Note this was an abstraction where there are actually hundreds of files.  I'll keep this in mind moving forward.  thx

Comment: So does fileB and fileC has lots of other includes too? Unfortunately it can be a too big spaghetty to untagle it. Try to be more specific with those files and the exact error message you get. Do you have this one only or many other errors?

Comment: Just a quick summary, though you've probably already understood this: if you're trying to access a global function that's already in fileC, in the other files, just declare the function, e.g. `void myFunc(int);` (no extern necessary there).  If you're trying to access a global variable, you want `extern int dog;` in the other files.

Comment: In the end, I created a class with the members and methods static so that any instantiation from those files point to and use/build upon the same material.